# Generating & outputting random number on website (w/ cookie & IP address restrictions)

Tags: javascript

I am a complete JS newbie, so apologies for asking what I think may end up being an overly-simplistic question.

Here's what I am looking to do:

Whenever a user visits a certain page, that page will display a randomly generated number. The page will generate a new random number for each NEW visitor, but the same visitor should always get the same number, i.e. there should be some sort of cookie and maybe IP tracking installed to make sure that the same visitor doesn't get a different number if he visits the page later on (e.g. the next day).

I don't really have any clues as to where to start...any tips?

Thanks much in advance!

P.S. This isn't a homework assignment or anything; it's a side project that I am trying to work on.

Comment: Cookies can also be set without JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery with two plugins:

jquery.random:

http://www.rockechris.com/jquery/jquery.random.js.html

jquery.cookie:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Can post examples if you need them?

As for IP tracking that would have to be done on the server side...